# Не работает консоль Yii2 на удаленном сервере

Tags: php, yii2

При попытке запустить любую команду через консоль yii2 выдает ошибку:

```
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
Content-type: text/html

Exception 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'Unable to determine the entry script file path.'

in /hsphere/local/home/razzwan/razzwan.yii2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Request.php:62

Stack trace:
#0 /hsphere/local/home/razzwan/razzwan.yii2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php(130): yii\base\Request->getScriptFile()
#1 /hsphere/local/home/razzwan/razzwan.yii2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/controllers/HelpController.php(421): yii\base\Component->__get('scriptFile')
#2 /hsphere/local/home/razzwan/razzwan.yii2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/controllers/HelpController.php(241): yii\console\controllers\HelpController->getScriptName()
#3 /hsphere/local/home/razzwan/razzwan.yii2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/controllers/HelpController.php(67): yii\console\controllers\HelpController->getDefaultHelp()
#4 [internal function]: yii\console\controllers\HelpController->actionIndex(NULL)
#5 /hsphere/local/home/razzwan/razzwan.yii2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(55): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#6 /hsphere/local/home/razzwan/razzwan.yii2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(151): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#7 /hsphere/local/home/razzwan/razzwan.yii2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Controller.php(91): yii\base\Controller->runAction('', Array)
#8 /hsphere/local/home/razzwan/razzwan.yii2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(455): yii\console\Controller->runAction('', Array)
#9 /hsphere/local/home/razzwan/razzwan.yii2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(167): yii\base\Module->runAction('', Array)
#10 /hsphere/local/home/razzwan/razzwan.yii2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(143): yii\console\Application->runAction('', Array)
#11 /hsphere/local/home/razzwan/razzwan.yii2/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(375): yii\console\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\console\Request))
#12 /hsphere/local/home/razzwan/razzwan.yii2/yii(18): yii\base\Application->run()
#13 {main}
```

Значения по-умолчанию я нигде внутри фрэймворка не менял. Откуда взялась такая ошибка, и что с ней делать? Хотелось бы работать удаленно через консоль.

**(Добавлено по просьбе отвечающего)** $_SERVER=

```
array(34) {
  ["LC_PAPER"]=>
  string(11) "ru_UA.UTF-8"
  ["LC_ADDRESS"]=>
  string(11) "ru_UA.UTF-8"
  ["HOSTNAME"]=>
  string(15) "***"
  ["LC_MONETARY"]=>
  string(11) "ru_UA.UTF-8"
  ["TERM"]=>
  string(5) "xterm"
  ["SHELL"]=>
  string(7) "/bin/sh"
  ["HISTSIZE"]=>
  string(4) "1000"
  ["SSH_CLIENT"]=>
  string(24) "***.***.***.*** ***** 22"
  ["LC_NUMERIC"]=>
  string(11) "ru_UA.UTF-8"
  ["SSH_TTY"]=>
  string(10) "/dev/pts/0"
  ["USER"]=>
  string(7) "user"
  ["LS_COLORS"]=>
  string(440) "no=00:fi=00:di=00;34:ln=00;36:pi=40;33:so=00;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=01;05;37;41:mi=01;05;37;41:ex=00;32:*.cmd=00;32:*.exe=00;32:*.com=00;32:*.btm=00;32:*.bat=00;32:*.sh=00;32:*.csh=00;32:*.tar=00;31:*.tgz=00;31:*.arj=00;31:*.taz=00;31:*.lzh=00;31:*.zip=00;31:*.z=00;31:*.Z=00;31:*.gz=00;31:*.bz2=00;31:*.bz=00;31:*.tz=00;31:*.rpm=00;31:*.cpio=00;31:*.jpg=00;35:*.gif=00;35:*.bmp=00;35:*.xbm=00;35:*.xpm=00;35:*.png=00;35:*.tif=00;35:"
  ["LC_TELEPHONE"]=>
  string(11) "ru_UA.UTF-8"
  ["MAIL"]=>
  string(23) "/var/spool/mail/user"
  ["PATH"]=>
  string(46) "/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin"
  ["LC_IDENTIFICATION"]=>
  string(11) "ru_UA.UTF-8"
  ["INPUTRC"]=>
  string(12) "/etc/inputrc"
  ["PWD"]=>
  string(40) "/***/local/home/user"
  ["LANG"]=>
  string(11) "en_US.UTF-8"
  ["LC_MEASUREMENT"]=>
  string(11) "ru_UA.UTF-8"
  ["SHLVL"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["HOME"]=>
  string(27) "/***/local/home/user"
  ["LOGNAME"]=>
  string(7) "user"
  ["SSH_CONNECTION"]=>
  string(37) "******* 22"
  ["LESSOPEN"]=>
  string(24) "|/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s"
  ["LC_TIME"]=>
  string(11) "ru_UA.UTF-8"
  ["HISTTIMEFORMAT"]=>
  string(14) "[%d/%m/%y %T] "
  ["G_BROKEN_FILENAMES"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["LC_NAME"]=>
  string(11) "ru_UA.UTF-8"
  ["_"]=>
  string(5) "./yii"
  ["OLDPWD"]=>
  string(27) "/***/local/home/user"
  ["PHP_SELF"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]=>
  float(1448568934.9327)
  ["REQUEST_TIME"]=>
  int(1448568934)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте что вы не переопределяете `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']`. Если переопределения нет то решение в лоб это определить этот параметр в запускаемом файле `yii` перед запуском `$application = new ConsoleApplication($config);`:

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = __DIR__ . '/yii';
```

Comment: Я использую переадресацию в файле .htaccess С этим может быть связано?

Comment: Ошибка перестала возникать, но команды все равно не выполняются. Выводится список команд, как будто команды нет.

Comment: Нужно больше информации. Какая команда, файл, что в файле, тип подключения (через ssh?). `.htaccess` нужен апачу, php его никак не воспринимает. Ошибка очень странная, попробуйте установить чистый yii2-app-basic и запустить `yii` там. Я думаю проблема где-то внутри проекта.

Comment: У меня на локальном сервере все работает без ошибок. Устанавливал проект на удаленный клонированием, возможно где-то неправильно прописались маршруты? Подключение, да, через ssh. Я попытался в скрипте вывести переменную ```echo $_SERVER['argv'][1];``` но ```PHP Notice:  Undefined index: argv in *** on line **``` Т.е. такой переменной не существует почему-то.

Comment: Скиньте результат `var_dump($_SERVER)`

Comment: Добавил в вопрос.

Comment: Запускаю файл yii командой ```./yii "здесь что бы ни писал, всегда выводится список команд, как-будто команда отсутствует"```

Comment: Да, еще, каждый раз в конце выводится сообщение "Content-type: text/html". На локальном такого нет.

Comment: Похоже `./yii` не принимает список аргументов (`'argv'` отсутствуют). И непонятно почему. `php yii` выдаст тоже самое?

Comment: Да, то же самое.

Comment: На удаленном сервере Php собрана как CGI http://php.net/manual/ru/install.unix.commandline.php там не определены эти переменные. И что теперь мне с этим делать?

Comment: `php -r "var_dump(\$_SERVER);"` содержит `argv`? Что с `php -v`?

Comment: `argv` должны быть полюбому. И `SCRIPT_FILENAME` если вы запускаете скрипт. С CGI у вас всё должно работать.

Comment: ОК, значит пишу в службу поддержки.